# Playing a game, what measurement of speed is u/s?

Tags: unity-web-player

I've been playing attack on Titan, a game based on the anime, and have recently enabled the speedometer so I could judge how fast my character is going. Unfortunately, it uses either a made-up or poorly translated unit of measurement. Does anyone know what u/s is, and how it relates to mph?

Comment: Is is possible to add a screenshot?

Comment: I would venture a guess to say that u/s is "units per second". I can only guess that since it's a unity game, it's referring to unity units (typically 1 unity unit = 1 meter). The conversion rate of 1 meter per second would equal 2.23694 miles per hour. Of course this depend on if the game is truly using a 1 to 1 scale.

Comment: @onewho good guess but I would like to see a screenshot and maybe a link to the game if it's free so we could check your guess ;)

Comment: http://fenglee.com/game/aog/

Comment: @Hellreaver I took a brief look at the game, but didn't see "u/s", is there a specific command you used to show the value?

Comment: @onewho press p and go into the menu. On the first menu, on the bottom right, it should say 'speed'. Enable it, and it'll show under your reticle

Comment: @Hellreaver I don't see the option for showing speed. I may have a different version then what you have, or maybe you're on a different browser (I'm using firefox). [Here is what I see when I go into settings](http://i.imgur.com/LaxHYm2.png)

Comment: @onewho sorry, after you enter the game

Comment: @Hellreaver that's the same option screen I see during game play as well. I did get a speed value to show when playing on the race map, but it displayed as a simple value, and was not displayed as "u/s". However seeing as it is built using unity and it is a development build I think I'm going to stand by my guess that "u/s" is Unity "units per second". If you are willing to accept that I will form it into an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into the game I feel I can safely determine that "u/s" stands for "units per second".

Since this game is built using the [Unity game engine](https://unity3d.com/), we can safely assume that units refers to "Unity units". [By default 1 Unity unit is equal to 1 meter.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/724157/the-default-units-in-unity-are-meters-right-.html)

[The conversion rate of meters per second(in this case "u/s") to miles per hour(mph) is 1(u/s) to 2.23694(mph).](http://www.calculateme.com/Speed/MetersperSecond/ToMilesperHour.htm)

In my experimentation with the game my character (Mikasa) ran at a standard speed of 12 m/s. This would translate to 26.8432 mph. According to my research on fastest possible foot-speed the [current world record is 27.78 mph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footspeed), so while 26.8432mph seems like a lot, it is possible for a person to run that fast (though not for an extended period of time).